# Python tkinter cut down path but open as full directory

Tags: python, tkinter, listdir, tkinter.optionmenu

Here is my full Python code:

```
from tkinter import *
import glob
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import tkinter as tk
import pyautogui
import datetime

#date & time
now = datetime.datetime.now()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SIGN OFF")
root.minsize(840, 800)

# Add a grid
mainframe = tk.Frame(root)
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.pack(pady=100, padx=100)

# Create a Tkinter variable
tkvar = tk.StringVar(root)


# Directory
directory = "C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/work/data/to-do"
choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.jpg"))
tkvar.set('...To Sign Off...') # set the default option

# Dropdown menu
popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, tkvar, *choices)
tk.Label(mainframe, text="Choose your sign off here:").grid(row=1, column=1)
popupMenu.grid(row=2, column=1)

label2 = tk.Label(mainframe, image=None)
label2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, rowspan = 10)

# On change dropdown callback.
def change_dropdown(*args):
    """ Updates label2 image. """
    imgpath = tkvar.get()
    img = Image.open(imgpath)
    img = img.resize((240,250))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    label2.image = photo
    label2.configure(image=photo)


tk.Button(mainframe, text="Open", command=change_dropdown).grid(row=3, column=1)


def var_states():
    text_file = open("logfile.txt", "a")
    text_file.write("TIME: %s, USER: %s, One %d, Two %d\n" % (now,os.getlogin(), var1.get(), var2.get()))
    text_file.close()
    print("One %d, Two %d" % (var1.get(), var2.get()))

var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Ingredients present in full (any allergens in bold with allergen warning if necessary)", variable=var1).grid(column = 2, row=1, sticky=W)
var2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="May Contain Statement.", variable=var2).grid(column = 2, row=2, sticky=W)
var3 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Cocoa Content (%).", variable=var3).grid(column = 2, row=3, sticky=W)
var4 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Vegetable fat in addition to Cocoa butter", variable=var4).grid(column = 2, row=4, sticky=W)
var5 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Instructions for Use.", variable=var5).grid(column = 2, row=5, sticky=W)
var6 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Additional warning statements (pitt/stone, hyperactivity etc)", variable=var6).grid(column = 2, row=6, sticky=W)
var7 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Nutritional Information Visible", variable=var7).grid(column = 2, row=7, sticky=W)
var8 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Storage Conditions", variable=var8).grid(column = 2, row=8, sticky=W)
var9 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Best Before & Batch Information", variable=var9).grid(column = 2, row=9, sticky=W)
var10 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Net Weight & Correct Font Size.", variable=var10).grid(column = 2, row=10, sticky=W)
var11 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Barcode - Inner", variable=var11).grid(column = 2, row=11, sticky=W)
var12 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(mainframe, text="Address & contact details correct", variable=var12).grid(column = 2, row=12, sticky=W)

def user():
    user_input = os.getlogin()
    tk.Label(mainframe, text = user_input, font='Helvetica 18 bold').grid(row = 0, column = 1)


user()


def save():
    # pyautogui.press('alt')
    # pyautogui.press('printscreen')
    # img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
    # img.save('paste.jpg', 'JPEG')

    var_states()


tk.Button(mainframe, text = "Save", command = save).grid(row = 20, column = 1)


root.mainloop()
```

When I run the code, there will be a dropdown of jpg files. Currently It shows the full directory like so:

[image]

I have created a post earlier on how to trim down the path and got something like this:

```
files = os.listdir("C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/work/data/to-do")
print(files)
```

But If I use that code above, it will not open the path when clicked `open` because it doesn't have the full path name.

What I am trying to do is, cut down the path name for display purposes and open the image by following the original full path.

As an example:

The current drop-down menu shows `C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/work/data/to-do/img1.jpg`
My desired result is `img1.jpg` but in the background open the whole path of above.

> **Copy comment**: this is what I have tried
>
> ```
> directory = os.path.splitdrive("C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/work/data/to-do")
> choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory[1:], "*.jpg"))
> ```
>
> , but says
>
> ```
> expected str, bytes or os.Pathlike, not tuple.
> ```
>
> Have added `[1:]` because the path is split into 2 and returning the 2nd part of it.

Comment: …Add the directory back to `imgpath`?  You control what’s opened.

Comment: Use a `dict` to map file name to full path.

Comment: Read about [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Show only the filename in `OptionMenu` but get original full path from selection.

Create your own `OptionMenu` which holds from all images the full path in a `dict` and shows only the filename as options.

---

1. Define your own widget `FileNameOptionMenu` by inheriting from `(tk.OptionMenu)`

   ```
   class FileNameOptionMenu(tk.OptionMenu):
       def __init__(self, parent, directory, extension, callback):
   ```
2. Get from all images the full path and extract the `filename`.
   Save every full path in a `dict` using the `filename` as `key` and the full path as `value`.

   ```
           # Save result from `glob` in a `dict`
           self.glob = {}
           for fpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, "*.{}".format(extension))):
               filename, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.split(fpath)[1])
               self.glob[filename] = fpath
   ```
3. Define a variable which holds the selected option for later usage.
   Init the inherited `tk.OptionMenu` with the `list` of the `keys` from the `dict`.
   Pass the `class method self.command` as `command=`.
   Save the `callback` for later usage.

   ```
           self.selected = tk.StringVar(parent, 'Select a image...')
           super().__init__(parent, self.selected, *list(self.glob),
                            command=self.command)

           self.callback = callback
   ```
4. This `class method` get called on every click option selection.
   On call, it calls the `self.callback`, which is `ImageLabel.configure`, with the full path of the selected option.

   ```
       def command(self, val):
           self.callback(image=self.glob.get(self.selected.get()))
   ```
5. Define your own widget `ImageLabel` by inheriting from `(tk.Label)`.
   This class extends the `tk.Label.configure` to handle `.configure(image=<full path>` instead of `.configure(image=<image object>`.

   ```
   class ImageLabel(tk.Label):
       def __init__(self, parent):
           super().__init__(parent, image=None)
   ```
6. Overload the inherited `class method tk.Label.configure`.
   Catch the name argument `image=` and replace the passed full path with a `image object`.

   ```
       def configure(self, **kwargs):
           key = 'image'
           if key in kwargs:
               # Replace the filepath with the image
               fpath = kwargs[key]

               img = Image.open(fpath)
               img = img.resize((240, 250))
               self._image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

               kwargs[key] = self._image
   ```
7. Call the original `tk.Label.configure` to show the image

   ```
           super().configure(**kwargs)
   ```

> **Usage**:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import glob, os

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label_image = ImageLabel(parent=self)
        self.label_image.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.option_menu = \
            FileNameOptionMenu(parent=self,
                               directory='C:/Users/eduards/Desktop/work/data/to-do',
                               extension='jpg',
                               callback=self.label_image.configure
                                               )
        self.option_menu.grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***

Comment: whats the difference between `class` and `def`?

Comment: `class` is a `OOP` term, read [tutorial/classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), and is used for `OOP` programming. Using `class inheritance` you can extend a default `class`, e.g. `tk.Label`, to your own needs. A `def` is a function for functional programming.